# What is _ALPHA_ macro?(windows device driver)

Tags: c, winapi, wdk

What is `_ALPHA_` macro?
I found this macro [in this code](https://github.com/weixu8/RegMon/blob/2109b6741d6bc665075ca9ea8562ccbebd773f9e/DD/REGSYS.C#L35).
What do you use this　macro  for?
Please tell me this macro or its references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a macro that is `#define`d if the file is being compiled for [DEC Alpha architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Alpha). With Windows, of course, one must note that Alpha support was there for

> Windows NT (discontinued after NT 4.0; and pre-release Windows 2000 RC1)

it means that in practice it is never `#define`d.

Comment: Thank you for repling!I was able to  understand code from before.